# Express dynamic include route based on user type

Tags: node.js, express

Need some help or any clue including/requiring dynamic routes at runtime in express, its confusing but i try my best.

This is just an example of app routes configuration right now

```
    app.use('/',    require('./routes/public'));
    app.use('/u',   require('./routes/user'));
    app.use('/a',   require('./routes/admin'));
```

for example **require('./routes/public')** will include something like this

```
router.get('/',                     home.index);                             
router.get('/faq',                  faq.index)
```

also **require('./routes/user')** will include this

```
router.get('/dashboard',            user_home.index);                             
router.get('/accounts',             user_acc.index)
```

also **require('./routes/admin')**

```
router.get('/dashboard',            adm_home.index);                             
router.get('/accounts',             adm_acc.index)
```

i have installed passportjs so its easy to check if the user is authenticated, also if it is, user contains 1 property type, eg: 1 = user, 2 = admin.

req.user.type = 1 or 2, req.isAuthenticated()...

what i need is inject depending user type 1 or 2, require('./routes/user') or require('./routes/admin') at runetime, cos i dont want to declare invalid routes for an user type user example including admin, or backwards.

Right now, all routes are visible or valid but i need to check every controller for user type, also i dont want the '/a' OR '/u' routes prefix.
All routes must be under '/'.

Answer (score 0):

Request runs to first matched path. You can render page, throw error or call `next` to get next middleware. Below some router examples.

```
'use strict'
var express = require ('express');
var app = express();

var publicRouter = express.Router();
publicRouter.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('ROOT'));
publicRouter.get('/account', function (req, res, next) {
    if (!is-user)
        res.send('Hello guest')
    else
        next();
});

var userRouter = express.Router();
function isUser (req, res, next) {
    // return next() on user logon, and error otherwise
    return next();  
}
userRouter.use(isUser);
userRouter.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => res.send('/dashboard'));
userRouter.get('/account', (req, res) => res.send('Hello user'));

var adminRouter = express.Router();
function isAdmin (req, res, next) {
    // return next() on admin logon, and error otherwise
    return next(new Error('Access denied'));
}
adminRouter.get('/manage', (req, res) => res.send('/manage'));

app.use(publicRouter);
app.use(userRouter);
app.use('/admin', isAdmin, adminRouter); // "/admin/manage", not "/manage"

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {    
    res.send(err.message);
});

app.listen(2000, () => console.log('Listening on port 2000'));
```

Another way is

```
app.get('/', do-smth);
app.get('/dashboard', isUser, do-smth);
app.get('/manage', isAdmin, do-smth);
```